# Android: runOnUiThread() Runnable Sequencing

Tags: android, multithreading, java-native-interface, handler, runnable

I have two JNI native methods that callback Java methods in my UI.

1) Display progress..
2) Dismiss progress

Both of the above calls are definitely in sequence. They both call Java methods that create new runnables as follows:

```
m_Activity.runOnUiThread( new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    DisplayProgressUpdate( m_ProgressPercent );
  }
} );
```

--

```
m_Activity.runOnUiThread( new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    m_Progress.dismiss();
  }
} );
```

What I am seeing is that the dismiss runnable is happening before the progress update runnable completes. I would have thought that because they were called in sequence and because they are both being requested on the same (UI) thread that they would occur in sequence as well. Is this not the case?

Is this why I should be using something such as a Handler to synchronise/sequence these calls?

EDIT: OK, I implemented a Handler and still observed the same behaviour. It was actually my debug that confused me. It looked as though the Dismiss Java code was happening before the progress update had completed, but what it was in fact was the Java debug printing as soon as JNI called the Java method which did the posting to the handler - not the actual runnable thread itself. So.. tajonn07 was right in a way - the dialog box was closing before I had a chance to see it and my debug lead me astray. Thanks for helping guys.

Comment: Isn't there no guarantee that processes running on the same thread will complete sequentially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

runOnUiThread is not added on queue in android , this is called immediately when it invoke. 
     If you want queue / sequence(ie one after another), you have to use Handler.

Comment: not necessarily true. "If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread." [source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what you're seeing isn't the dismiss being executed first, but instead it's being executed so quickly after the display that it doesn't even show.

I would suggest using a handler. But even with a handler, if it's in your UI thread, it will freeze your screen.

It's a bit messy, but you could drop both those blocks of code inside another thread with a handler. It's not the cleanest solution but it should do the trick!

Comment: You are correct - I'm not seeing the dialog - thats fine. The problem I'm trying to resolve concerns what happens afterwards. I rotate my device and then the progress dialog reappears - and that is dependent upon a "show requested" flag that I've set. That and the LogCat output that I'm seeing is suggesting that the progress update hasn't finished before the dismiss is called. I think b.j.g has a point.